# TestNG test case execution count on Slack Notification

Tags: jenkins, testng

How to get slack notification of test case count from  **\target\surefire-reports\testng-results.xml using Jenkins File for Pipeline Job as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H86C.png)

I got notification on slack but not the count of test case